# putting an image in each category in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/waqLq62d/

and let me know how to put an image at the beginning of the category. so as it is shown in this picture.

[image]

I do not know how, thank you very much.

```
$('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: [data.d[300].nomindicador, data.d[500].nomindicador, data.d[600].nomindicador,data.d[700].nomindicador, data.d[900].nomindicador],
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {

            align: 'left',
            x: 10,
            y: -20

            }

        },
        yAxis: {

            title: {
                text: 'Resultado',
                 align: 'right'
            }

        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' dollars'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: -40,
            y:40 ,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to have to use the `useHTML` property on the `labels` object and set it to true.

Then, you have to use the `format` property to inject an HTML image in your label.

**Full working example here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/u3o416xb/

The code should look something like this:

```
labels: {
    x: -5,
    y: -20,
    useHTML: true,
    format: '<div style="position: absolute; left: 40px"> my label </div> <img style="height: 30px; width: 30px; margin-top: 10px"  src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-printer-icon-set/512/Plastic_model.png"></img>'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!. the images are perfect, but I want to keep text above the bars. How can i fix this?

Comment: Just edited to provide exactly what you wanted, but keep in mind, this is more of a CSS matter from here :)

Comment: Yes, but I need different images in each category.

Comment: you can try to use the `formatter` property instead of `format`, but this is not a question related to highcharts anymore.