# putting category and image in HIGHCHARTS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/waqLq62d/

and let me know how to put an image at the beginning of the category. so as it is shown in this picture.

[image]

I do not know how, thank you very much.

I want to keep pictures in the y-axis, and want to keep the category above the bars.I would be very grateful if you could help me.

```
   $('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: [data.d[300].nomindicador, data.d[500].nomindicador, data.d[600].nomindicador,data.d[700].nomindicador, data.d[900].nomindicador],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {

        align: 'left',
        x: 10,
        y: -20

        }

    },
    yAxis: {

        title: {
            text: 'Resultado',
             align: 'right'
        }

    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' dollars'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
     align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: -40,
        y:40 ,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573692/putting-an-image-in-each-category-in-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

you can have your custom HTML for the labels of axis.

for this you need to enable "useHTML" property and use formatter to insert your custom HTML into the chart.

```
labels: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return "<div class='imageClass'>2</div>";
    },
    align: 'left',
}
```

I update your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/waqLq62d/3/)

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: with css styling you can see it.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I want to show the image and the title continues to be above each bar.

Comment: can you update the fiddle with the image you want to show? that will help me to help you better.